# read element from an array in java

Tags: java, arrays

I have an instance of Object class (e.g. obj).

By using `obj.getClass().isArray()` I can confirm that it is an array.

Now I want to access elements of this array (like `obj[0]` or something like that).
Is it possible to do so?

Please help

Comment: Cast it to an object array. Then you'll probably be able to do it. But this sounds bad. What made you design your code this way ?

Comment: i have to read from servlet request scope and if result is an array, i have to return its first element. Casting to Object[] is working for me. Is this way not efficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply cast it to an `Object` array.

```
(Object[])obj[0];
```

Comment: What if the array is int[]?

Answer (score 0):

check the code below:

```
Object array = new String[]{"abc","def"};
    if(array.getClass().isArray()){
        Object[] aaa = (Object[])array;
        System.out.println(aaa[0]);
    }
```

Any non-primitive array can up-cast to `Object[]`

Answer (score 0):

`java.lang.reflect.Array` provides methods to dynamically access array elements. You can use `Array.get(Object array, int index)` to read elements and `Array.getLength(Object array)` to get its length.